# Java System.setProperty() not working in jar

Tags: java, classpath, native

so I have a java program that uses JNI and a hardware that uses some dlls as well where in it I need to set a path to its required dlls from Windows System properties, so library loading is out of the question (Not to mention I tried it and it wasn't working as intended).

I want to use `System.setProperty("path", "path/to/dll")` so less technically inclined users don't need to do so manually. 2 questions:

1. When I run it from Eclipse, it works fine, but as a jar file it doesn't. Why is this (I don't know how to see the console when running as a jar file)?
2. is it actually safe to do `System.setProperty("path", "path/to/dll")`?

Comment: *"(I don't know how to see the console when running as a jar file)"*  Run it from the command line with something like `java -jar the.jar`.  *"is it actually safe to do System.setProperty("path", "path/to/dll")?"*  Sure. It is typically ignored, but AFAIU 'safe'.  Does this app. have a GUI (is a desktop app.)?

Comment: Did you embed the resources (dll's) in the Jar?  Are the dll's accessible from the execution context of the Jar?  Try outputting the result of `new File(System.getProperty("path").exist()` to see if the path actually exists when the program executes

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was charged to do something else in the meantime I couldn't get this to work. Yeah it does have a GUI. And the path for now is actually existing. That's the idea when I deploy the app. Embed the required stuff in the JAR, check for the path and create if doesn't exist and then put the dlls in the path then add the actual path to the "path" property of windows, even if it is only temporary.

Comment: A system property is different than an environment variable, and you'd be setting it in a different shell anyway.  (Think about it-the ability to affect the system-wide path would be a security hole.)

Comment: Yeah I kind of did think it might be blocked because of security reasons. The only reason it works when running from Eclipse is probably for testing but I was still kinda hoping that it was something I just had to set.